# Look for values within interval, then count R

Tags: r, date, time, count

Beginner here. I have two data frames, one with a timestamp and letters

```
library(lubridate)
df1 <- data.frame (timestamp  = as.POSIXct(c("2021-07-11 02:22:22.000","2021-07-11 02:22:22.000", "2021-07-11 02:24:59.000","2021-07-11 02:26:59.000")),
              letter = c("A", "A", "B","C"))
```

and another one with a start and endtime

```
df2 <- data.frame (timestamp_start  = as.POSIXct( c("2021-07-11 02:22:22.000", "2021-07-11 02:24:59.000","2021-07-11 02:26:59.000")),
              timestamp_end = as.POSIXct(c("2021-07-11 02:23:59.000", "2021-07-11 02:25:59.000","2021-07-11 02:27:59.000")))
```

What I am trying to achieve is that it should count the occurences of the letters if df1$timestamp is within the start and end timestamp of df2. In the end, I want have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
result <- data.frame (timestamp_start  = c("2021-07-11 02:22:22.000", "2021-07-11 02:24:59.000","2021-07-11 02:26:59.000"),
               timestamp_end = c("2021-07-11 02:23:59.000", "2021-07-11 02:25:59.000","2021-07-11 02:27:59.000"),
               count_A = c("2", "0", "0"),
               count_B= c("0", "1", "0"),
               count_B= c("0", "0", "1"))
```

Do I need a loop for this? Please help me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr 1.1.0`, you can use `join_by` to do an overlap join and then use `tidyr::count`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>% 
  inner_join(df2, by = join_by(between(timestamp, timestamp_start, timestamp_end))) %>% 
  count(timestamp_start, timestamp_end, letter)
```

```r
      timestamp_start       timestamp_end letter n
1 2021-07-11 02:22:22 2021-07-11 02:23:59      A 2
2 2021-07-11 02:24:59 2021-07-11 02:25:59      B 1
3 2021-07-11 02:26:59 2021-07-11 02:27:59      C 1
```